# busybox list command show different time format for file last modified time

Tags: busybox

e.g. android busybox command:

```
busybox ls -ls foldername/
```

outputs are:

```
Jan  1  2015
```

or

```
Oct 16 14:18
```

The first one doesn't show time while second one does not show year.
How to make the output show complete date time e.g.`Oct 16 2019 14:18`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `--full-time` to the command to view the complete date.

```
busybox ls -ls --full-time foldername/
```

As stated on `ls` command's usage:

> --full-time     List full date and time